# How can button appears again on website after couple of seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my "X" button on website to appear every 30 seconds or so. So when people visit my site, they can close the "X" button and after they close, the "X" button will show up again in 30 seconds or so. How is it possible? I know how to delay the button to show

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Hide the div
          $("#button1").hide();
          // Show the div after 2s
          $("#button1").delay(2000).fadeIn(100);  
      });    
  </script>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: dont do that, sounds very annoy to users

Comment: use setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tell it to show every 30s.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#button1').show();
},30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add an onclick method for your button, and when it is triggered you do the same thing as when you fade in the button at start (hide then delay a fadein).

should be somthing like

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Hide the div
          $("#button1").hide();
          // Show the div after 2s
          $("#button1").delay(2000).fadeIn(100);  
          $("#button1").onclick(function() {
              
             $("#button1").hide();
             // Show the div after 30s
             $("#button1").delay(30000).fadeIn(100);  
          });
      });    
  </script>
```